# Generate absolute time from time difference in Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time, posixct

I have a Dataframe called "myseis" which contains Accelerationdata:

```
    X     Y     Z     dt
1  -0.843 3.854 8.247  0
2  -0.598 3.795 8.110 20
3  -0.402 3.834 8.325 19
4  -0.353 3.883 8.414 20
5  -0.117 4.059 8.404 20
6   0.039 3.854 8.159 20
7   0.235 3.726 7.894 20
8   0.372 3.706 7.717 20
9   0.451 3.903 7.835 21
10  0.568 4.197 8.061 19
```

I want to add a 5th column which contains the absolute time. Something like:

```
        X     Y     Z     dt    Date/Time
    1  -0.843 3.854 8.247  0    2018-08-020 10:00:00,000
    2  -0.598 3.795 8.110 20    2018-08-020 10:00:00,020
    3  -0.402 3.834 8.325 19    2018-08-020 10:00:00,039
    4  -0.353 3.883 8.414 20    2018-08-020 10:00:00,059
    etc.
```

So I want to add up the "dt" column (milliseconds) to the Starttime which is in POSIXct.

I kind of figured out that I could do it with:

```
time <- c(starttime)
i <- 1

while(i < nrow(myseis))
{
    i <- i+1
    time <- c(time,time[i-1]+myseis[i,4])
}
myseis <- data.frame(myseis,time)
```

On a small scale, this checks out but in this case, nrow(myseis) = 247118 and so this would take forever.

Is there another way? I want to plot a subset of this Dataframe later.

Thanks

Comment: R is a vectorized language and thus one can avoid using loops for most instances and see a huge performance improvement.  Take a look at the `cumsum` function.  `time+cumsum(myseis[,4])` should provide the result you are looking for.

Comment: This worked and it just takes a fraction of a second. Thanks a lot.